# How to instantiate a scikit-learn model from a string variable?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, yaml

I have a list of models as parameters in a YAML file.
When I read them into my Python script, they appear there as strings:

```
my_model = "LinearRegression()"
print(type(my_model)) #output: <class 'str'>
```

I want to initialize my sklearn model as:

```
model = LinearRegression()
```

but with `LinearRegression()` being a string variable.

At the moment, naturally, `model = my_model` is a string, and can't be fitted, etc.

How to instantiate the sklearn model from a string variable?

My use case: I want to put different models in a YAML file as params in order to sweep over them in the model fine-tuning procedure (a simple AutoML).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have few options:

1. Use `eval` as a quick&dirty solution:

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
model_str = 'LinearRegression()'
model = eval(model_str)
print(model)
```

Note: using `eval` is not a safe because it will execute any string so if you have no control about a string variable being executed a malicious code may be executed.

Also you need to import exact the same class before using eval. Without the first line the code will not work.

2. use `pickle.dumps`

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

model_class_serialized = pickle.dumps(LinearRegression)
print(model_class_serialized)
model_class = pickle.loads(model_class_serialized)
print(model_class)
```

In that case you do not need explicitly import classes from sklearn.

An example of saving models to YAML:

```
import pickle
import yaml

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC

models = [LinearRegression, RandomForestClassifier, LinearSVC]

with open('models.yml', 'w') as out_file:
    yaml.dump({m.__name__: pickle.dumps(m) for m in models}, out_file)
```

After that you can read YAML file like that:

```
import pickle
import yaml

with open('models.yml', 'r') as in_file:
    models = yaml.load(in_file, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
    models = {name: pickle.loads(serialized_cls) for name, serialized_cls in models.items()}

print(models)
```

Which produces:

```
{'LinearRegression': <class 'sklearn.linear_model._base.LinearRegression'>, 'LinearSVC': <class 'sklearn.svm._classes.LinearSVC'>, 'RandomForestClassifier': <class 'sklearn.ensemble._forest.RandomForestClassifier'>}
```

so you can easily instantiate these models:

```
model = models['RandomForestClassifier']()
print(model)
# model.fit(...)
```

Comment: I will use the first version (I can control for malicious code, and in fact use a config file from kedro to store a list of models to track in my training pipeline, where the present YAML output is not that efficient). But full agree the second option is more elegant. Thank you :)